# Get Current URL and Compare to HREF of link to leave submenu open

Tags: jquery, location-href

I have a simple menu that slides down more UL when the parent LI is clicked, if there is a child UL to follow...

I am trying to make it so when the menu is in a certain directory it will have that menu expanded by default rather than closed. I have tried a few things, but am just not getting it to work. Currently I have a IF statement comparing the PATHNAME with the Varibles and just telling that ID to keep the UL open... That has been as close as I can get.

Any suggestions on how to make the UL stay open if the page url is the same as the parent UL HREF?

You can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/RvGMQ/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got something to work here. Let me know if there is a better way if you come across this post...

I ended up creating a Meta Tag called MyTitle and gave it content to compare an ID to then display UL based on that Meta Tag.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu ul ul").hide();
    $("#menu ul li").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(300).siblings("ul").slideUp("slow");
    });

//created a meta tag called MyTitle to use as a way to open menu when needed. This function checks for the value of MyTitle. Got this from (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=569947)
var mytitle;
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (var x=0,y=metas.length; x<y; x++) {
  if (metas[x].name.toLowerCase() == "mytitle") {
    mytitle = metas[x];
  }
}

//Find the page currently on and display menu if need be.
var title = "" + mytitle.content;
if(title == "Resources")
    $("ul #resources").show();
if(title == "Conferences")
    $("ul #conferences").show();
```

etc..........